# Whats the easiest way to get sql 08 spatial data onto a map?

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, geospatial

I've got a DB with a whole bunch of records containing lat and long of points I want to get onto a map. The level of  detail I need is down to Australian street level and up to the country level and it can be either pure map data (suburbs, streets, etc) or aerial photos. This is purely for personal purposes and the output doesn't need to be production quality. I assume either Bing maps or Google Earth is the way to go - can anyone point me in the right direction for a very fast, simple implementation? Thanks!

Comment: What client side framework have you chosen for the map mash-up?

Comment: If anything needs actual coding then .NET is the preference. As I mentioned, this is not a customer facing project so client technology can be anything fast and nasty that just lets me visualise the data on a map.

Comment: DeepEarth should fit the need for a client side framework, it's written in C# for Silverlight. You'll still need a server side component for delivering the data AFAIK. For that, GeoServer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I've found for this so far is [Craig Dunn's Geoquery](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/Geoquery/). I need to spend a little more time getting familiar with it but on the surface it looks like a pretty neat tool.

Answer (score 1):

This could be some start - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx#id0080059

> SQL Server Management Studio 2008
>   includes a simple visualizer in the
>   form of a Spatial results tab in the
>   Query results window. This visualizer
>   works with a geography or geometry
>   column in the query results and plots
>   the spatial data types on a grid. If
>   multiple spatial columns appear in the
>   query results, you can choose the one
>   to visualize. The column to be
>   displayed must be in the SQL Server
>   binary format; using ToString() or
>   STAsText() won't work with the
>   visualizer.

Comment: Thanks for that, interesting article but other than the reference to Craig Dunn's Geoquery program it's mostly about the spatial results tab which doesn't give you any map overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what client side tool you choose for the mash-up you'll want to have an API for retrieving your SQL Server data in either image or vector format.  I haven't had any hands on experience with it but [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) should be able to [work with SQL Server Spatial Data](http://docs.geoserver.org/1.7.x/en/user/data/sqlserver.html).

From their [about page:](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/What+is+Geoserver)

> GeoServer can display data on any of the popular mapping applications such as Google Maps, Google Earth, Yahoo Maps, and Microsoft Virtual Earth. In addition, GeoServer can connect with traditional GIS architectures such as ESRI ArcGIS.

Hope this helps.